# Sending node request with req value as array index value

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express, mongoose

I have made a route to push a range of documents into a mongoose collection, each entry having the value of the next index in an array of defined upper and lower bounds. Doing it like this works fine for index bounds starting with 1. However, making the lower bound of the index a higher number, like 20 (so for example numbers of 20-30 stored in the array), will for obvious reasons return `undefined` as each array starts with index 0. Is there any way around this? Here's my code:

```
var list = [];
      for (var i = req.body.from; i <= req.body.to; i++) {
        list.push(i);
        Blank.create({
        number: list[i -1],
      })
      console.log(list[i - 1])
    }
```

Comment: If `from` and `to` are 20, 30 then what should `list` and `number` be assigned to?

Comment: @Ramesh if ```from``` = 20, and ```to``` = 30, then ```list``` should be an array containing numbers from 20 included to 30 included, and ```number``` should hold the value of each of the numbers if the array (so with the first iteration it should hold the number at index 0, with second iteration the valued at index 1 and so on until the very last number in that array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be simple:

```
var list = [];
for (var i = req.body.from; i <= req.body.to; i++) {
  list.push(i);
  Blank.create({
    number: i,
  })
}
```

If you are not using the list anywhere else then just:

```
for (var i = req.body.from; i <= req.body.to; i++) {
  Blank.create({
    number: i,
  })
}
```

Comment: Of course, perfect - thank you so much! 2 weeks in quarantine and being in front of my computer 24/7 make my brain melt sometimes...